# How to exit from artisan worker on disconnected beanstalk correctly?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, beanstalkd

I'm using laravel 5.1 with beanstalkd mantained with supervisor.

The trouble is:
1) artisan queue:work beanstalkd --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
2) sudo service beanstalkd stop

Thats all. I got 400G of errors in my laravel.log during 24h:

```
[2015-10-06 17:09:18] local.ERROR: exception 'Pheanstalk\Exception\ConnectionException' with message 'Socket error 111: Connection refused (connecting to localhost:11300)' in /home/glue/proj/crowdbanner/vendor/pda/pheanstalk/src/Socket/NativeSocket.php:45
```

How to avoid this correctly and stop worker when beanstalk is dead?

Answer (score 0):

As you would try/catch any other exception - and do whatever you need, from sleeping and trying again later, to exiting entirely.

```
try {
    // reserve a job
    // act on the job
    // delete the job if it's complete.
} catch (Pheanstalk\Exception\ConnectionException $e) {
    echo "can't connect to Beanstalkd";
    exit 99;
}
```